# UIView touch issue / question

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

Having a little trouble with my app.  I am questioning my approach.

Here is an image  [image: Sample App]

Basically i need the color wheel to spin in the transparent box.  What I have so far is working.  I can drag the color wheel and it will rotate.  The problem is I can touch and drag 'anywhere' on the screen and it will rotate.  I only want it to rotate in the 'window'.

I basically added a UIView and an UIImageView, added outlets to the ImageView and added code in touchesBegan and touchesMoved to perform the animation.  The wheel is a full circle image and subviews are 'clipped' to no show the lower half of the image.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *thisTouch = [touches anyObject];
    delta = [thisTouch locationInView:wheelImage];

    float dx = delta.x  - wheelImage.center.x;
    float dy = delta.y  - wheelImage.center.y;
    deltaAngle = atan2(dy,dx); 

    initialTransform = wheelImage.transform;   
  }

  - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
      UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint pt = [touch locationInView:wheelImage];

  float dx = pt.x  - wheelImage.center.x;
  float dy = pt.y  - wheelImage.center.y;
  float ang = atan2(dy,dx);

  //do the rotation
  if (deltaAngle == 0.0) {
    deltaAngle = ang;
    initialTransform = wheelImage.transform;
  }else
  {
    float angleDif = deltaAngle - ang;
    CGAffineTransform newTrans = CGAffineTransformRotate(initialTransform, -angleDif);
    wheelImage.transform = newTrans;
    
    currentValue = [self goodDegrees:radiansToDegrees(angleDif)];
    
  }

  }
```

Now...My questions are the following:

1. How can I get the touchesMoved/Began ONLY to work on the UIView or UIImageView?
2. Should I create a Custom UIView for this wheel and then just add it to my main view controller?
   2.a. If I do create a custom, will I have the same issue with the touches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider using a UISwipeGestureRecognizer and adding it to only the view in which you wish to recognize the swipe.

Comment: I added the recognizer.  Seems like it is working solely on the UIImageView, which is cool.  I just need to play with the animation.  very choppy if I use the same code as my touchedMoved.  I need to look into the recognizer to see how often it fires seems like only once per swipe.

Comment: Hmm, come to think of it a UIPanGestureRecognizer may work better in your case as it tracks the finger precisely as it moves across the view.

Comment: I am using Swipe as of now.  I got it to work great.  Once i get the creative down I might come back to Pan and see how it works.  Thanks for the leads!

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution is to add a `BOOL` var that is set `true` when the touch started in the region you like:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *thisTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [thisTouch locationInView:wheelImage.superview];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(wheelImage.frame, p))
    {
      rotating = YES;
      // rest of your code
      ...
    }
}
```

and:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  if (rotating)
  {
     // your code
  }
}
```

Remember to reset `rotating` in `touchesEnded` and `touchesCanceled`.

Comment: or `if ((rotating = CGRectContainsPoint(wheelImage.frame, p)))` so it will set a NO result as well.

Answer (score 1):

if you subclass UIImageView and put that code in it, you will only get the touches from that view, you will probably need to set the acceptsUserInteraction to YES. also change the locationInView: to self; if you are loading from a nib, be sure to set the class to your new subclass for that UIImageView.